# Is there any maximal $\mathbb Z$-linearly independent subset of (additive group) real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

By adding some irrational number to the set {1,$\sqrt{2}$}, can i extend my initial linearly independent set?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$-linear independence is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$-linear independence (clear denominators), so a Hamel basis does the job (it has cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$ and exists by Zorn's Lemma and cannot be "written down").